# Using PHP to create a new directory, and a file in that directory

Tags: php, file

I recently started to mess around with some HTML and PHP, and have run into what is probably a super easy to solve error, but one I have not for the life of me been able to fix.

In a nutshell, what I'm trying to do is create a directory, then create a .txt file in that directory with the same name, something to the effect of "/number/number.txt". While it seems simple to create a file, or to create a directory, I'm having no end of troubles trying to do both.

Here's my code:

```
mkdir($postnum, 0777);
chmod($postnum, 0777);

$post = "/" . $postnum . "/" . $postnum . ".txt";
$post = boards(__FILE__) . $post;

$po = fopen($post, 'w+') or die("Can't open file");
chmod($post, 0777);
```

A few issues I ran into writing this, I read that using mkdir I could set the permissions of the directory I create, but despite doing what I believe to be the right way of doing so, it didn't do anything. So I ran chmod right after.

Then, I had hoped that just /$postnum/$postnum.txt would work for the directory to open, but I get the die text when I try just that, I had to add in the "boards(**FILE**) part to get it to work. (Side note, "boards" is the directory I'm working in)

Even then, while it doesn't give me "Can't open file", it isn't creating the file or anything.

I've made certain that any file or folder even remotely interacting with the files has had it's permissions set to 0777, so it's likely not an issue with that. (Also, I know that having all my files completely open like that may not be the best idea; once I get this working properly, I'll be sure to set the permissions to something more safe)

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: `file_put_contents($file_name)` is a good helper function to easily write to a file. Try that out and see if it doesn't help you.

Answer (score 2):

```
making directory and creating path:-

$new_folder=mkdir('uploads\\'.$folder_name, 0777, true);

('uploads\\'.$folder_name)->path where you create folder like www->upload->folder name(whatever you provide)

$path="uploads\\".$folder_name."\\";//if you want to provide path you can provide this way
```

Answer (score 1):

The mkdir function takes a path relative to the root of the **filesystem**, not the document root.

If you're on a *nix system, your website document root is likely in a path such as /var/www/sitename/html, but you're trying to create /number/number.txt which your account doesn't have permissions to do. Change the path you pass into mkdir to somewhere in the filesystem you have permissions to create folders and files and your code should work.

Edit:

The code in your question doesn't actually attempt to write anything. By calling fopen you've created a file handle, but you need to call [fwrite](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fwrite.php) to actually write data to the file. As suggested by @JamesSwift, you may want to take a look at [file_put_contents](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php).

Comment: Sorry, I didn't really explicitly say this anywhere in my description, the folder (/numbers) is being created, however, the file (/numbers/numbers.txt) is not being made, despite the program not hitting the die text. Going off of what you said about mkdir taking the path relative to the filesystem root, however I tried to set it up correctly based on that, and received a "website has a programming error" page when I try to view it. The full system path for the folder would be "/home/username/webhome/boards/number/". My permissions start with /username/, though. Which should I start with?

Answer (score 0):

Here, try this :

```
$root = realpath($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]);
mkdir("$root/root_website_folder/php/testing_folder", 0777);
```

PHP uses your real path not the virtual one, we assign to $root the real path on your machine than add the virtual path of your website root